# How do I setup windows samba sharing on my second hard drive so that all users can create and delete files in Unity?

Tags: samba, privileges

How do I setup windows samba sharing on my second hard drive so that all users can create and delete files in Unity?  I need to setup samba with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear. Specify what systems do you have, and what exactly you want to achieve. Is that share on windows? (btw. you can't have samba share on windows.. windows shares are smb (or other) and samba speaks smb protocol so in IT world you need to be really specific). What does it mean create and delete files in Unity? Unity is windows manager, it can't create and delete files on its own.

I guess you want to mount windows share in ubuntu, and to do that you use mount command. f.e

sudo mount -t "filesystemname" \ip.ip.ip.ip\nameofshare \mnt\mountpoint

take a look here:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man8/mount.8.html

as for privileges in ubuntu you need to read this: 
http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

and maybe this,

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man1/chmod.1.html